# How do I learn how to configure CreateWebHostBuilder to serve Razor pages, and other addins like Websockets?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a default website that runs well on MacOS

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

However I need to run Websockets, and MVC code, however the following Kestrel configuration doesn't allow me to view `index.html` on port 500001

How do I (learn how to) properly configure this for MVC and Websockets on MacOS?

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost
        .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        // Increase Shutdown timeout to accomodate background tasks.
        //.UseShutdownTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseKestrel((hostingContext, options) =>
        {
            if (hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 50001, listenOptions =>
                {
                    listenOptions.UseHttps("localhost.p12", "1234");
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuring ASP.NET itself is done inside your `Startup` class (which you've already specified with `UseStartup<Startup>()` and not inside your `Program` class.

Open your `Startup.cs` file and ensure you have:

- `UseStaticFiles()` to serve static files like `index.html` (`index.html` is not a Razor View for ASP.NET MVC nor a Razor Page, as those have the extension `.cshtml` and are generally named after their corresponding controller actions in `TitleCase`.
- `UseMvc()` to use the ASP.NET Core MVC system with `Controller` and Razor View support.

Comment: Where do I type this in? The compiler doesn't recognize UseStaticFiles.  I added `Microsoft.ASPNetCore` and `Microsoft.ASPNetCore.StaticFilles`, cleaned the bin and obj, restarted Visual Studio code, and checked that I'm using Core 2.2 on MacOS.  Any suggestions? I even tried in a brand new project.

Comment: Same goes for UseMVC

Comment: @TLDR My answer specifically mention your `Startup.cs` file which contains your `class Startup`. They go inside the `Configure` method. I recommend you read ASP.NET Core's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I created a brand new project, and copied my code over with your suggestions.  My csproj was borked somehow

Comment: @TLDR Does your issue resolved by creating a new brand project?